# Change the position of the labels in a node - Jung2 Java Graph Library

Tags: java, legend, jung

this is my code to represent an *UndirectGraph*.

I load *node objects* and *strings* in two HashTable which will then be displayed in a frame.
I want to change the position of the Labels of the nodes,  and I have to use a *CircleLayout*.

The nodes that are located on the left side have the Label topped with the edges of the graph, representing it always to the right of the node. I need the nodes on the left side have the *Label* on their left, at least until the middle of the total number.

```
    UndirectedGraph<String, String> graphStruct = new UndirectedSparseMultigraph<String, String>();

    Hashtable<String, NodeData> nodeCollection = new Hashtable<String, NodeData>();

    Hashtable<String, EdgeData> edgeCollection = new Hashtable<String, EdgeData>();

                                       ...
                                       ...
                                       ...

    edgeCollection.put(""+edge, new EdgeClass(edge, "Id+"+edge));

                                       ...
                                       ...
                                       ...

    VisualizationViewer<String, String> vv = new VisualizationViewer<String, String>(new FRLayout<String, String>(graphStruct));
    vv.getRenderContext().setVertexFillPaintTransformer(new VertexColor(nodeCollection));
    vv.getRenderContext().setEdgeLabelTransformer(new ToStringLabeller<String>());
    vv.getRenderContext().setVertexLabelTransformer(new NodeId(nodeCollection));

    JLabel label = new JLabel();
    label.setOpaque(true);
    label.setText("Graph");
    vv.add(label);  

    PluggableGraphMouse inter = new PluggableGraphMouse();
    inter.add(new TranslatingGraphMousePlugin(MouseEvent.BUTTON3_MASK));
    inter.add(new PickingGraphMousePlugin());
    inter.add(new ScalingGraphMousePlugin(new CrossoverScalingControl(), 0, 2 / 1.2f, 1.2f));
    vv.setGraphMouse(inter);
    vv.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1600,1000));
    vv.setLocation(500, 500);

    vv.setGraphLayout(new CircleLayout(graphStruct));

    final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setTitle("Graph Rappresentation"); 
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().add(vv);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
```

I would also insert a legend to the side of the graph, to be filled with values ​​according to the type of graph.
If anyone can help me thank you, good evening.

Comment: It is not clear to me what the problem is. Is there any way you could show a screenshot that illustrates what you have and which part you want to change?

Answer (score 3):

JUNG is increadibly powerful. It's easy to quickly do nice graph visualizations with it. When you want to configure or tweak the visualization, the basic, common modifications are easy, but more specific ones can be a bit fiddly. Particulary, there is not always appropriate documentation, and you might have to take a look at the JUNG source code to grok it. (However, nearly everything seems to be *possible*, at least).

In this case, it should be sufficient to call

```
vv.getRenderer().getVertexLabelRenderer().setPosition(Position.AUTO);
```

on your `VisualizationViewer`. This will cause the labels of the vertices to be placed "away from the center". So when there is a vertex in the upper left area of the window, the label will be placed in the upper left above the vertex.

If this is not sufficient, you may implement an arbitrary positioning algorithm, by additionally calling

```
vv.getRenderer().getVertexLabelRenderer().setPositioner(positioner);
```

where `positioner` is an approproate implementation of the `Positioner` interface. (In fact, when setting the position to `Position.AUTO`, it uses an implementation of this interface that is called [OutsidePositioner](http://jung.sourceforge.net/doc/api/edu/uci/ics/jung/visualization/renderers/BasicVertexLabelRenderer.OutsidePositioner.html)...)

---

The description of what the actual problem is was indeed hard to grasp, so here are two images showing the difference:

With default vertex label placement, the vertex labels may be painted over the edges (as here for vertex v2) :

[image: VertexLabels01]

When setting the position to `Position.AUTO`, the labels are always placed "outside":

[image: VertexLabels02]

Here is an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve):

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

import org.apache.commons.collections15.Transformer;

import edu.uci.ics.jung.algorithms.layout.FRLayout;
import edu.uci.ics.jung.graph.DirectedSparseMultigraph;
import edu.uci.ics.jung.graph.Graph;
import edu.uci.ics.jung.visualization.VisualizationViewer;
import edu.uci.ics.jung.visualization.renderers.Renderer.VertexLabel.Position;

public class JUNGVertexLabelPositionsTest 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        final Graph<String, String> g = getGraph();
        VisualizationViewer<String, String> vv = 
            new VisualizationViewer<String, String>(
                new FRLayout<String, String>(g));
        Transformer<String, String> transformer = new Transformer<String, String>()
        {
            @Override
            public String transform(String s)
            {
                return s;
            }
        };
        vv.getRenderContext().setVertexLabelTransformer(transformer);

        // Adjust the label placement based on the position 
        // of the vertex relative to the window:
        vv.getRenderer().getVertexLabelRenderer().setPosition(Position.AUTO);

        f.getContentPane().add(vv);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setSize(300,300);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }


    public static Graph<String, String> getGraph() 
    {
        Graph<String, String> g = new DirectedSparseMultigraph<String, String>();
        g.addVertex("v");
        for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
        {
            g.addVertex("v"+i);
            g.addEdge("e"+i, "v", "v"+i);
        }
        return g;
    }
}
```

(Concerning the legend: I don't know a simple solution for this from the tip of my head, but you might consider asking this as a separate question)

Comment: Thank you very much for your great help Mark in a few lines I've saved a lot of time and research into the code of this library, congratulations.
I will follow your advice to open a different Question for the legend.
See you soon, good evening.